# How to remove the border that show after clicking a picture

Tags: html, css

So i have this image, everytime i click it there is border around it.
This is what i mean

[image]

Heres the CSS for it

```
#form {
    position:fixed;
    right: -50px;
    border:none;
    top: 350px;
    z-index: -1;
    cursor: help;
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
div id="form" class="sidepan pic">
     <a href="url" target="_blank"><img src="imagelink"></a>
     </div>
```

anyone know how to remove this purple border? it appears only when clicked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `outline: none` on `a:focus`.

```css
#form {
  position: fixed;
  border: none;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: help;
}
a:focus {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<div id="form" class="sidepan pic">
  <a href="url" target="_blank">
    <img src="imagelink" alt="image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. accepting this as the answer in 7 mins :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `outline` on your `a` tag:

```
#form a{
   outline: none;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnskxwh0/)

Answer (score -2):

Try this in your CSS:

```
a img {
  border: none;  
}
```